# Regex search for exact dates in Month day, year

Tags: regex, date, replace, ms-word

Hoping someone might be able to help me with this. I'm using regex in word and am having trouble with the search pattern. I want to search for dates in the "Month day, year" and am using this:

(<[ADFJMNOS]*>) ([0-9]{1,2},) ([0-9]{4})

However, it keep selecting all words leading up to the date. For example, if I have:

It's a beautiful Day on March 3, 2011.

It'll select "Day on March 3, 2011" because the D matches the string. What am I missing to get it to just match at the month onwards?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That's because your rule states 'take everything starting with a D until I find some numbers', you have to alter it so that it will only find one word:

```
(<[ADFJMNOS]\w*\s>) ([0-9]{1,2},) ([0-9]{4})
```

This rule says take everything start with a D (or any of the other letters) until I reach a space then and then, as long as there a numbers, continue.

The `\w` means any character that could be found in a word, so a space won't count, `\s` means a space.

You would probably find this even more accurate if, instead of just single characters, you use the beginnings or even whole words of all of the months: `(Jan\w+|Feb\w+ ... )`

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm currently using MS Word for this though and it doesn't seem to like the \w and \s.

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure what word takes but you should be able to replace it them with: `\w --> [A-Za-z]` `\s --> [\t\n ]`.